# Mysql select query returns nothing if string contains spaces or just alphabetical characters

Tags: php, mysql

**UPDATE**

I was connecting to the wrong database. Yes, please spit on me, i deserve it. I am very sorry for the trouble.

If i try this, MySQL (via PDO) does not return any  result

```
$db = new db('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$email = 'alexandre@domain.com';
$mot_de_passe = 'Un mot et un chiffre 8?';
$bind= array(":email"=>$email, ":mot_de_passe"=>$mot_de_passe);
$results = $db->select("users", "email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe", $bind);
```

But if try this, MySQL returns the row correctly.

```
$db = new db('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$email = 'alexandre@domain.com';
$mot_de_passe = '1234';
$bind= array(":email"=>$email, ":mot_de_passe"=>$mot_de_passe);
$results = $db->select("users", 'email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe', $bind);
```

It also returns nothing if `$mot_de_passe = 'Pourquoi';` So i assume it only accepts numbers. Why is that? The Password column is of type VARCHAR(255).

**UPDATE**

I'm using [this PDO Wrapper class](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/#select) to manage the transactions with the database.

**DEBUG INFO**

Using PDO syntax :

```
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * from `users` where email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe');
$sth->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':mot_de_passe', $mot_de_passe, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->debugDumpParams();
```

produces this debugging info:

```
SQL: [81] SELECT * from `users` where email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe
Params:  2
Key: Name: [6] :email
paramno=-1
name=[6] ":email"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [13] :mot_de_passe
paramno=-1
name=[13] ":mot_de_passe"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Here is the query from the mysql's general_log file:

```
SELECT * from `users` where email='alexandre@domain.com' AND mot_de_passe='Pourquoi ?'
```

If i use this query directly, it returns the intended result. If i use it via PDO it does not find the result.

Comment: Removed PDO tag as irrelevant to the question.

Comment: 1) Added the $db object to the question. It refers to the active connection to mysql.
2) utf8_general_ci

Comment: From the code snippets you pasted, presumably, `alexandre@domain.com` only has one password and not the other? Or are there two accounts in the database with `email=alexandre@domain.com`?

Comment: @pinkgothic: I had assumed that `mot_de_passe` had been changed within the database between the two attempts... obviously, if it's neither that nor multiple records, there's not much of a question here.

Comment: @eggyal: I'd normally assume that, too, but especially if no immediate issue is apparent to people who work with this sort of code a lot, I find it's best to ask about those assumptions and make sure. (I do think you're probably right, but let's see what the OP says.)

Comment: @eggyal sorry about not mentioning the db class. Question updated.
@ pinkgothic no, only one account with that email value.

Comment: From reading that library's source, it appears that errors will be silently discarded unless you call [`setErrorCallbackFunction()`](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/#setErrorCallbackFunction).  Have you set a callback so that you can see/handle errors (one could just use `'print_r'`)?

Comment: @pixeline: So, are you changing the password in the database before you test each password, like eggyal assumed? :)

Comment: @pinkgothic yes, i am.

Comment: If you are still using the wrapper, please could you address the question raised in [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610681/mysql-select-query-returns-nothing-if-string-contains-spaces-or-just-alphabetica#comment30843571_20610681) re setting a callback for error handling?  If you're no longer using the wrapper but rather are now using PDO directly, please could you call [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to something other than the default `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`?

Comment: Also, why does the general_log show whitespace and question mark after `'Pourquoi'`?

Comment: "Yes, please spit on me, i deserve it. I am very sorry for the trouble." Whoa! No worries about the trouble; people are happy to help you figure out the problem... and you did find the problem, so that was a success. Everyone makes mistakes.  No-one ever deserves to be spat on. That's not nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you use `urldecode()` function? It brakes special symbols and have no relation to mysql escaping.

Try this:

```
$email = 'alexandre@domain.com';
$mot_de_passe = 'Un mot et un chiffre 8?';
$bind= array(":email"=>$email, ":mot_de_passe"=>$mot_de_passe);
$results = $db->select("users", "email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe", $bind);
```

Try this one in PDO style:

```
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * from `users` where email=:email AND mot_de_passe=:mot_de_passe');
$sth->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':mot_de_passe', $mot_de_passe, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

and check, is this query returns something?

```
SELECT * from `users` where email='alexandre@domain.com' AND mot_de_passe='Un mot et un chiffre 8?';
```

Comment: sorry, it's a leftover from a former try.

Comment: And check your `mot_de_passe` column, is there a "Un mot et un chiffre 8?" in it?

Comment: Can you tell please, what certain character from `'Un mot et un chiffre 8?'` string being broken by urldecode()?

Comment: @Your Common Sense sorry, my bad. `urldecode` in this case - not. Check my answer about new information.

Comment: The PDO style request does not return the intended row neither.
The vanilla SQL request returns the intended row. So the error is in PDO?

Comment: It's interesting. Let's try to add this: $sth->debugDumpParams();
after execute and show us the output result. You can check your final SQL by "general_log" option of mysql server, if you have access to it.

Comment: I updated the question with the output result. I'm investigating about the general_log option, will get back if i manage to set that up. Thank you.

Comment: Well, i managed to turn on general_log, so i can see the final query. It's really weird: the produced query is correct, and if i use it plainly, i get the intended result. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Hm... it's really interesting. Do you use one database in plain and script? May be you have 'dev' database without this row?

Comment: oh my god. You're right, i'm not testing against the right database. It works against the right one. Sorry all for the trouble. Ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from the title, Mysql select query **never** fails if string contains password.

Speaking of your own code that doesn't return the desired result - just debug the code and double check the data.

Comment: i did otherwise i wouldn't ask on SO. The code works fine if the password is "1234" yet fails if the password is "Word", "word", "Word And". Test procedure is: 1./ change the value in the mysql table before the testing, 2./ use the same string in the php code 3./ Run the script with a simple `print_r($results);`

Comment: There is no point in asking on SO why *your own code* doesn't work. Obviously, genuine Mysql and PDO never do no harm to passwords. So - it's only your own code to blame. Do you realize that?

Comment: According to my tries, if i write the query in vanilla mysql, it returns the row. If i write it using PDO syntax, it does not find the row. That's why i went to SO: maybe there is something i'm overlooking? I've only recently started using PDO so there may be something i'm missing.

Comment: There is **no** PDO in your code, but some homebrewed library built on top of it. If you are only recently started using PDO then you will do yorself a huge favor if start using it raw, at least until learn it well